# Is Stacking multiple IF conditions on a IF condition allowed in cloud firestore rules?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I was having trouble with stacking IF conditions on a rule I set.

This is the condition (does not work because does not allow read on the own user's document.):

```
allow read: if (isLoggedIn() && request.auth.uid == request.resource.data.userId) || (isLoggedIn() && isUserManager(db)) || (isLoggedIn() && isUserAdmin(db));
```

This is the part where I believe does not work?

```
isLoggedIn() && request.auth.uid == request.resource.data.userId)
```

This seems to work:

```
allow create: if (isLoggedIn() && isUserSeller(db)) || (isLoggedIn() && isUserManager(db)) || (isLoggedIn() && isUserAdmin(db));
```

If the WRITE worked and I used a similar structure, it means `request.auth.uid == request.resource.data.userId` is guilty one here? or is my IF condition faulty here?

The `request.auth.uid == request.resource.data.userId` should check for the document's field called `userId` and see if the request user id ==, else it should be false right? the problem is that the user can not see their own documents. Only Managers and Admins can see it, as I have tested.

Entire rule:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  
  match /databases/{db}/documents {
    match /appPref/{doc} {
        // for apk, pdf dropbox links which are not that important to secure
      allow read: if isLoggedIn();
      allow write: if false;
    }
    
    match /catalogs/{doc} {
      allow read: if isLoggedIn();
      allow write: if isUserAdmin(db) && isLoggedIn();
    }
    
    match /changelogs/{doc} {
      allow read: if isLoggedIn(); 
      allow write: if isUserAdmin(db) && isLoggedIn();
    }
    
    match /marquees/{doc} {
      allow read: if isLoggedIn(); 
      allow write: if false;
    }

    match /uploadedRecords/{uRecord} {
      allow read: if (isLoggedIn() && request.auth.uid == request.resource.data.userId) || (isLoggedIn() && isUserManager(db)) || (isLoggedIn() && isUserAdmin(db));
      allow create: if (isLoggedIn() && isUserSeller(db)) || (isLoggedIn() && isUserManager(db)) || (isLoggedIn() && isUserAdmin(db));
      allow delete: if isUserAdmin(db);
      
      function isUserSeller(db) {
        return (get(/databases/$(db)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.userType == 'seller');
      }
    }

    match /users/{userId} {
        // user info (the most important data here), only admin or user can access.
        allow read: if isUserOwnerAdminManager(db, userId) && isLoggedIn();
      allow write: if isUserOwnerAdmin(db, userId) && isLoggedIn();
    }
    
  }
  
  function isLoggedIn(){
        return request.auth != null;
  }

  function isUserOwnerAdmin(db, userId){
    return request.auth.uid == userId || isUserAdmin(db);
  }
  
  function isUserOwnerAdminManager(db, userId){
    return request.auth.uid == userId || isUserAdmin(db) || isUserManager(db);
  }

  function isUserAdmin(db) {
    return (get(/databases/$(db)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.userType == 'admin');
  }
  
  function isUserManager(db) {
    return (get(/databases/$(db)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.userType == 'manager');
  }
}
```

This is an example of a document from uploadedRecords:

```
- /uploadedRecords/some random doc id/{"userId":"userIDabc","moreData":"someData"...}
```

This is an example of a document from users:

- /users/userIDabc/{"userId":"userIDabc","displayName":"Mario"...}

This is the trigger from the application to get the stream on firestore:

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('uploadedRecords')
          .where('timeStamp', isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: _startTime)
          .where('timeStamp', isLessThanOrEqualTo: _endTime)
          .where('userId', isEqualTo: user)
          .orderBy('timeStamp', descending: true)
          .snapshots();
```

As you can see, the trigger where it matters is from `.where('userId', isEqualTo: user)`

Comment: Security rules on their own don't do anything.  They are only triggered when app code attempts a query.  Please edit the question to show 1) the entire set of rules (not just "allow"), 2) the app code that is being rejected by the rules, 3) the document data you're working with.  There should be enough information in the question so that anyone can reproduce the situation.

Comment: alright, edited to add the entire set of rules, examples of relevant documents path and data.

Comment: Where is your app code that triggers these rules?

Comment: done, added an example for the stream to trigger the main rule.

Comment: Are you saying that the query against uploadedRecords fails with `allow read: if true` as you show in your complete set of rules?

Comment: sorry, the allow: if true was after I posted the question, corrected the post. btw with allow: if true works. That's why I switched to it until I find a solution.

Comment: Now, show us the actual data involves proves that the `user` variable matches the current user's uid, which also matches the contents of the userId field in the documents you wish to receive.  We can't verify that any of those things are correct here.

Comment: I can vouch for the user variable being the correct one as I can see the document userId field compared to the userId field on users/{userId}/{userId: 'correctUserId'} but I have to say I am not sure if `request.resource.data.userId` from firestore rules variable is correct.

Comment: You might want to use the local rules debugger to track this down on your own.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/test-rules-emulator

Comment: alright, thanks, I will try the rules emulator.